# How to make "this" implicit?

Tags: scala, implicit

I have a class instance of which should be implicitly passed inside methods of this class. Something like this:

```
class Game(player: Player) {
  protected implicit val implicitThis = this // This is the workaround I use now

  def play = player.makeMove() // makeMove takes an implicit game: Game
}
```

Comment: I saw similiar solution in some presentation on ScalaDays this year. I think your solution isn't that bad.

Comment: I'm also using a similar kludge.

Answer (score 1):

You can package it into a trait.

```
trait ImplicitMe {
  protected implicit def implicitMe: this.type = this
}

class Game extends ImplicitMe {
  private def foo(implicit g: Game) = g
  def bar = foo
}
```

(Might want to add `@inline` on the trait also.)